# composite primary key which contains a foreign key

Tags: jpa, orm, composite-primary-key

I have an entity called UserWithRoles:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserWithRoles implements Serializable
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
  private int id;

  private String name;

  private String password;

  @OneToMany( mappedBy = "user" )
  private List<UserRole> roles;
}
```

A UserRole entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@IdClass( UserRolePK.class )
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED )
@DiscriminatorColumn( name = "roleType", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 10 )
abstract public class UserRole implements Serializable
{
  @Id
  // It should be mapped as a foreign PK by user.id (user field declared below)
  private int userID;

  @Id
  private String roleType;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn( name="user_id", referencedColumnName = "id" )
  private UserWithRoles user;  
}
```

The primary key class UserRolePK:

```
@Data
public class UserRolePK implements Serializable
{
  private int userID;
  private String roleType;  
}
```

I want to create a composite PK to UserRole: UserWithRoles.id + UserRole.roleType
How can I map it to the database? Should I use the UserWithRoles type in the PK class instead of the ID? Is it a good idea at all? Or I just should use normal PK to UserRole? The relation would be something like that between the ClientOrder and ClientOrdetItem entities: (ClientOrder.id + ClientOrderItem.num)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Derived Identity.

You need to change `UserRole` to look like this:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@IdClass( UserRolePK.class )
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED )
@DiscriminatorColumn( name = "roleType", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 10 )
abstract public class UserRole implements Serializable
{    
  @Id
  private String roleType;

  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn( name="user_id", referencedColumnName = "id" )
  private UserWithRoles user;  
}
```

That is, get rid of the `userID` field and add an `@Id` annotation to the `user` field.

And change `UserRolePK` to look like this:

```
@Data
public class UserRolePK implements Serializable
{
  private int user;
  private String roleType;  
}
```

That is, change the name of the `userID` field to `user`, to match the name of the `@Id` field in `UserRole` (but its type must still match the type of the `UserWithRoles` PK field, `id`).

Derived identity is discussed in JPA 2.1 spec, section 2.4.1.